# With scons, how do you link to prebuilt libraries?

Tags: c++, build-process, scons, build-tools

I recently started using scons to build several small cross-platform projects. One of these projects needs to link against pre-built static libraries... how is this done?

In make, I'd just append "link /LIBPATH:wherever libstxxl.lib" on windows, and "stxxl.a" on unix.

Comment: One small note, it's better to say `LIBS=['foo']` rather than `LIBS=['libfoo']`. The former gives you platform independance (ie, in POSIX you will get a libfoo.a, and in Windows a foo.lib)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to document the answer, as I already located it myself.

```
Program( 'foo', ['foo.cpp'], LIBS=['foo'], LIBPATH='.' )
```

Adding the LIBS & LIBPATH parameters add the correct arguments to the build command line.

More information [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/0.97/HTML/scons-user/x655.html).

Comment: What if I want to link a library that's already compiled as a `.so`?

Comment: @AaronFranke the question was specifically for static libraries, not dynamic libs (.so on unix)